# How to speed up the plot of a large number of rectangles with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot a large number of rectangular objects with Matplotlib.
Here a simple code with n randomly generated rectangles.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
plt.xlim([0, 1001])
plt.ylim([0, 1001])
n=10000
for i in range(0,n):
    x = random.uniform(1, 1000)
    y = random.uniform(1, 1000)
    ax.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((x, y),1,1,))
plt.show()
```

With n=10000 it takes seconds, but if we increase the number of rectangles to 100K it takes too much time.
Any suggestion to improve it, or different approach to have a plot in a reasonable time?

Comment: I know you are asking for matplotlib, but in your case gnuplot might perform better. I is known, that matplotlib is quite slow compared to gnuplot; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911655/gnuplot-vs-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm going to try gnuplot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding all the patches to the plot at once with a `PatchCollection` produces around a 2-3x speedup with n = 10,000, I'm not sure how well it will scale to larger numbers though:

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
plt.xlim([0, 1001])
plt.ylim([0, 1001])
n=10000
patches = []
for i in range(0,n):
    x = random.uniform(1, 1000)
    y = random.uniform(1, 1000)
    patches.append(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((x, y),1,1,))
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I confirm that your approach produces a 3x speed up. With 100K objects It takes ~40s against ~2m30s.

Comment: My `Polygon`s look different if added via a `PatchCollection` than if added to the axes directly.  Sadly this makes the plot inferior and unusable.