# Looping through a list to generate a packing simulation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am working on a code that focuses on efficiently packing boxes into a package car. Right now, I am in the beginning stages of the code. I'm in the process of learning python while doing this code. I have generated a set of boxes and sorted them by their bottom surface area. I am now trying to plot them in a way where the largest surface area is placed first and the rest follow.

This is what I have so far, but I am getting an error when I try to generate the coordinates for the rectangles. I know there has to be more to it. For example, once the first box is placed the second has to be placed where the the end of the surface is.
**UPDATED CODE 5:01 PM EST. No error message, but not plotting the rectangles**

```
#Random Integer/Number Generator
import numpy
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.patches as patches
#%matplotlib inline
import random

def createBox():
#this is what randomly generates the dimensions of the boxes and saves to list
N= int(input ("Enter number of boxes :"))
list1 = [];
list2 = [];
list3 = [];
list4 = [];
for i in range(0,N):
    x = random.randint(1,4) #non integers would be random.random or random.unif
    y = random.randint(1,4)
    z = random.randint(1,4)
    box = [x,y,z];
    area = [x,y]
    list1.append(box)
    list2.append(area)
print(list1)
print(list2)

#Here is where the organizes the dimensions of the box
for i in list2:
    result = numpy.prod(i)
    list3.append(result)
list3.sort(reverse = True)
print(list3)

for box in list2:
    l = box[0]
    w = box[1]
    res = [l,w]
    list4.append(res)
list4.sort(reverse = True)
print(list4)
lims = (0,100)
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect = 'equal')
#ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((0,0),list4[0][0],list4[0][1]))
plt.ylim(lims)
plt.xlim(lims)
patchlist = [];
for box in list4:
    x = box[0]
    y = box[1]
    patchlist.append(patches.Rectangle((x,y),0,0))
    ax1.add_collection(PatchCollection(patchlist))
plt.show()
```

I got the bottom code from
[How to speed up the plot of a large number of rectangles with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905305/how-to-speed-up-the-plot-of-a-large-number-of-rectangles-with-matplotlib) .

I'm not sure if it makes complete sense, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: *"I am getting an error when I try to generate the coordinates for the rectangles."* Please include the full error message in your question.

Comment: Please include the error message in order for other users to help you!

Comment: Hi! I updated my code to what I have now. I'm not getting an error message, but it's not plotting any rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rectangles have width and height 0 so they are invisible.

```
patchlist.append(patches.Rectangle((x,y),0,0))
```

Change the zeros to something > 0 and you should see them. I changed them to 1 and they showed up at the bottom left of the drawing area.

Bobby

Comment: Hi! I no longer get an error, however, it just gives me an empty coordinate system.